# How to convert single screen app to tab based app using react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react, react-native-navigation

I am trying my hands on react-native-navigation but I am stuck with a simple problem.

The app has a login page which doesn’t have tabs. (very much similar to facebook login page)(Image ref -
[The image is just to give an idea. Image Courtesy -
 Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk26N.jpg)
After the user logs in, I want to convert to a tab based app, and I want different navigation stacks for both tabs (as it happens in apps like **Quora**)
(Image ref - [Again Image is just a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX9CJ.png))

I am using mobx for state management.

I know its a common use case but I am confused between the two options known to me -

1. provide a reaction to user login variable and change from single screen app to tab based app. (The only concern is the lack of animation when the reaction on isLoggedIn happens)
   Eg - 
   App.js

   ```
   constructor() {
   reaction(() => auth.isLoggedIn, () => app.navigateToHome())
   reaction(() => app.root, () => this.startApp(app.root));
   app.appInitialized();
   ```

   }

   ```
   startApp(root){
       switch (root) {
         case 'user.login':
           Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
             tabs: [
               {
                 label: 'One',
                 screen: 'user.login',
                 icon: require('./assets/one.png'),
                 selectedIcon: require('./assets/one_selected.png'),
                 navigatorStyle: {},
               }
             ]
             screen: {
               screen: root,
               title: 'Login',
               navigatorStyle: {
                 screenBackgroundColor: colors.BACKGROUND,
                 statusBarColor: colors.BACKGROUND
               },
               navigatorButtons: {}
             }
           })
           return ;
         case 'user.home':
           Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
             tabs: [
               {
                 label: 'One',
                 screen: 'user.home',
                 icon: require('./assets/one.png'),
                 selectedIcon: require('./assets/one_selected.png'),
                 navigatorStyle: {},
               },
               {
                 label: 'Two',
                 screen: 'user.home',
                 icon: require('./assets/two.png'),
                 selectedIcon: require('./assets/two_selected.png'),
                 title: 'Screen Two',
                 navigatorStyle: {},
               }
             ],
             animationType: 'slide-down',
           });
         return;
         default:
             console.error('Unknown app root');
       }
     }
   ```
2. Use single screen app but implement tabs in the home screen. With this method, I would have to implement different navigation stack for both tabs by myself. (react-native-navigation already implements this. So, no worries in method 1 regarding navigation stack)

Eg - App.js

```
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
          screen: {
            screen: root,
            title: 'Login',
            navigatorStyle: {
              screenBackgroundColor: colors.BACKGROUND,
              statusBarColor: colors.BACKGROUND
            },
            navigatorButtons: {}
          }
        })
```

Home.js

```
<Tabs>
        <Tab
          titleStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 10}}
          selectedTitleStyle={{marginTop: -1, marginBottom: 6}}
          selected={true}
          renderIcon={() => <Icon containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12}} color={'#5e6977'} name='whatshot' size={33} />}
          renderSelectedIcon={() => <Icon color={'#6296f9'} name='whatshot' size={30} />}
          >
          <Feed />
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          titleStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 10}}
          selectedTitleStyle={{marginTop: -1, marginBottom: 6}}
          selected={selectedTab === 'profile'}
          title={selectedTab === 'profile' ? 'PROFILE' : null}
          renderIcon={() => <Icon containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12}} color={'#5e6977'} name='person' size={33} />}
          renderSelectedIcon={() => <Icon color={'#6296f9'} name='person' size={30} />}
          onPress={() => this.changeTab('profile')}>
          <Profile />
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
```

What are the best practices in managing tabs in react-native?
And in my use case which method I should go with ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem - did you manage to reach anywhere?

Comment: I'm having the same problem - did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve top tabs, you would need to start a single screen app and then define top tabs. You can do something like this below.

```
    Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
     screen: 'FirstScreen'
     title: 'FirstScreenTitle'
     topTabs: [
       {
         screen:'FirstTabScreen'
       },
       {
         screen:'SecondTabScreen'
       }
     ]

    });
```

Register each tabs as individual screens first.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `Navigation.startSingleScreenApp()` and then moving to `Navigation.startTabBasedApp()` (Option 1) is the recommended approach.

The only problem you say you face is that there is no animation in Option 1, but you have that option actually: Add a transition animation to the new navigator object:

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
  // ...
  animationType: 'slide' // optional, add transition animation to root change: 'none', 'slide-down', 'fade'
})
```

Look for the animationType property in the docs, both in [startSingleScreenApp](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api?id=startsinglescreenappparams) and [startTabBasedApp](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api?id=starttabbasedappparams).